# Python Web scraping - How to locate the Co-ordinates of the map element?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am doing a bit of web scraping and using selenium with python. I am not able to locate a map element and get the latitude and longitude from it. Can anyone have a look at the code. This is my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the application home page
driver.get("http://www.zoopla.co.uk/to-rent/commercial/details/41716558?search_identifier=c2df4fb926a1dd55be2a0e31c706380b#1cy1zTwJA1aKrxcV.97")
maps = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='listing-details-tabs']/ul/li[2]")
maps.click()

laltong=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='bto-rent-commercial']/script[6]/text()")
print(latlong.text)
```

I understand that my xpath for locating the element is totally wrong, because I am not even able to locate that element. Any suggestions on this ?
Here is a link to the webpage - http://www.zoopla.co.uk/to-rent/commercial/details/42080041?search_identifier=f02093ba0369b1204ac8cf6369e419f5#RuZu0HmxXSL3auBJ.97 and click on Map and nearby.

The latest code that i tried is,

```
laltong=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Click to see this area on Google Maps']/div/div[1]/a")
print(latlong.get_attribute("href"))
```

and the error is,

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@title='Click to see this area on Google Maps']/div/div[1]/a"}
```

Comment: No suggestions are possible without knowing the HTML of the element(s) you're trying to target.

Comment: Ya. Please kindly click on the link of the webpage that I have added with the question and then click on the tab map. Thanks

Comment: Please remove the link and make sure the question can be answered without leaving the site. It's no good for Q+A otherwise

Comment: Ok @Clive . Thanks I will do that

Comment: @Clive I am not able to post the HTML as it's very much complicated. sorry. Kindy refer the webpage if you can. Thanks

Comment: The link is fine. It's really helpful for scenarios like this where posting alot of HTML makes it harder to solve. I'm not seeing any lat/long on the Map & nearby map. Wouldn't the address be more useful? How are you planning to use lat/long?

Comment: @JeffC No - I am having a lot of data from other websites as well. wherein I have taken the lat and long data. Lat & long can be taken from the href element of the google maps (that you see in the bottom of the current map as Google). I just don't know how to locate that Google Element first

Comment: @JeffC Kindly please see my latest code that I have updated in the question. My idea is If I can get the href of that element then I can split it and get my lat and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that come later, if you:

1. navigate to [this link](http://www.zoopla.co.uk/to-rent/commercial/details/42080041?search_identifier=f02093ba0369b1204ac8cf6369e419f5#RuZu0HmxXSL3auBJ.97)
2. click on the Map & nearby tab
3. click on the Google logo in the bottom left of the map (white text on light background... it's hard to see)

That will open the map that OP is looking for.

Now with that out of the way... the `A` tag looks like

```
<a target="_blank"
  href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.552574,-0.052437&amp;z=15&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3"
  title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"
  style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;">...</a>
```

where the `href` attribute is the important bit that we want.

To get this `A` tag, we can use a CSS selector `"a[title='Click to see this area on Google Maps']"` to find the element. From there you would get the `href` attribute, which I'm assuming you know how to do already.

---

After your update, I see that you are using XPath. Your XPath is close but the element that contains `title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"` is the `A` that you want so the XPath would be `"//a[@title='Click to see this area on Google Maps']"`. I would suggest you use CSS selectors because they are faster and less prone to errors.

[CSS selectors reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS selectors tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

Comment: np. I updated the answer to show the XPath... you were close.